# creating container through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to create container through javascript and set the css properties.

for some reason, the below code does not work.

js

```
var maincontainer = $('#maincontainer');
var tablecontainer = $('<div/>',{'class':'tablecontainer'});
maincontainer.append(tablecontainer);
```

css

```
#maincontainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
#tablecontainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.tablecontainer` instead of `#tablecontainer` You need a class selector not id selector.

Comment: @PSL Post that as an answer.

Comment: @PSL: that does not work either

Comment: Is your code inside the `document.ready()` handler?

Comment: How can you tell that it doesn't work? The CSS is identical for both elements. How are you verifying this?

Comment: It does work. If you're just looking at it (and not Inspecting it,) then at a glance, how will you know it's there or not? They have exactly the same styling. Different styling shows the fix @PSL provided works: http://jsfiddle.net/uCsJp/

Comment: @PSL: Thanks..it works..I did not give the div in html

Answer (score 0):

js

```
var maincontainer = $('#maincontainer');
var tablecontainer = $('<div class="tablecontainer" />').appendTo(maincontainer);
```

css

```
#maincontainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
.tablecontainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var maincontainer = $('#maincontainer');
var tablecontainer = $('<div/>');
tablecontainer.addClass('tablecontainer');
maincontainer.append(tablecontainer);
```

Css

```
#maincontainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
.tablecontainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed `class` to `id` and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7wkg4/
(also changed bg color of new div to green so it could be seen in the demo)

Answer (score 0):

your html should be:

```
<div id="maincontainer"></div>
```

as for your css, I modify the table container with lower width and height as well as the colour so that you can tell the difference:

```
#maincontainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
#tablecontainer{
  background-color:blue;
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
}
```

as for your js/jquery, this is how you should be doing it:

```
var maincontainer = $('#maincontainer');
var tablecontainer = '<div id="tablecontainer"></div>';
maincontainer.append(tablecontainer);
```

Comment: For your information, it should be an ID with '#' instead of class with '.' since you defined it as an ID in your css.

Answer (score 0):

i use $(document).ready as tigger

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('<div/>',{
    'id':'tablecontainer'
}).appendTo('#maincontainer');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wkg4/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/7wkg4/5/